# Module not found in ngx-toastr

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ngx-toastr

I am not able to find the answer..

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/animations' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/common' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/common/http' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/core' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/core' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/core' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/core' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/http' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/node_modules/@angular/router' in '/Users/vasanthan/Mean projects/MEAN-Library/src/app'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! library@0.0.0 start: `ng build && node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the library@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vasanthan/.npm/_logs/2018-09-02T15_52_34_108Z-debug.log
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please provide some more info about this problem. where and how you face this error? what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you run `yarn install` in the root of your application?  It looks like you don't have any dependencies in the  `node_modules` folder.

Otherwise, you need to provide more information.  Are you using the Angular CLI?  It seems like your missing all the  @angular dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command:

```
npm install ngx-toastr --save
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is using ngx-toaster with Angular 15 and using Visual Studio Code make sure when you import the package from 'ngx-toastr'

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
```

By default Visual Studio Code with import it from:

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr/public_api'; // completely wrong and it wont work
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete **node_modules** folder manually
run `npm cache clean --force`
and run `npm install`