# ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/animations/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/browser.js

Tags: node.js, angular

i m trying to make a data table with Materials angular and CRUD , so when i had install npm toast ( ngx-toastr) , an error displayed to me like this

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/animations/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/browser.js
**Photo**
[image]Angular cli version 9.1.9

Package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^17.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^9.0.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.21",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"

}
```

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: And the error happens after running `npm install ngx-toaster` or if happens when you try to run the project?

Comment: after running npm install ngx-toaster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anytime you encounter an error like this (`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, ...`) it's likely that one of your packages (or your app) is trying to use a dependency that it does not have access to. This is likely caused by version conflict or simply not installing a dependency correctly

Your best bet might be to delete your `node_modules` directory if you have one and then run `npm install` in the root of your application.

You can find out more by reading the responses to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138676/module-not-found-in-ngx-toastr) related to `ngx-toaster`.